# CIFilter not working Playground iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift-playground

While trying to get a CIFilter to work in iOS 10 playgrounds, I keep getting an invalid context message in the console and a crash.

I have seen CIFilters work in OS X playgrounds with use of kCIInputImageKey, as in:

```
obj.setValue(img, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

I am assuming that kCIInputImageKey is not supported on iOS and seek confirmation of this as well.

Here is the error I get in the playground console:

Jul  9 20:59:53  UITest[7538] : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

Here's my code:  The last line crashes in playground, but works fine in the simulator.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let iv = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 11, y: 39, width: 354, height: 589))

//UIBeginGraphicsContew
let moi = UIImage(named:"moi")!
let moici = CIImage(image:moi)!
let moiextent = moici.extent
let center = CIVector(x: moiextent.width/2.0, y: moiextent.height/2.0)

let smallerDimension = min(moiextent.width, moiextent.height)
let largerDimension = max(moiextent.width, moiextent.height)

let grad = CIFilter(name: "CIRadialGradient")!
// OS X only??
//grad.setValue(moici, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
grad.setValue(center, forKey:"inputCenter")
grad.setValue(smallerDimension/2.0 * 0.85, forKey:"inputRadius0")
grad.setValue(largerDimension/2.0, forKey:"inputRadius1")

let gradimage = grad.outputImage!
```